# How can i select numbers bigger than

Tags: string, select, expression

i have a situation i have strings that contain something like this:

```
, time:219857 msec,
, time:1127 msec,
, time:38 msec,
, time:515 msec,
, time:9345 msec,
, time:423385 msec,
```

I need to select that string in each line where the number is bigger then **150000**.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str[] = new String[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        str[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    Long targetId;
    for(int i =0;i<6;i++){
        targetId = Long.parseLong(str[i].substring(str[i].indexOf(':')+1, str[i].indexOf('m', str[i].indexOf('m') + 1)-1));
        if(targetId > 150000) {
            System.out.println(str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is match any number with 7 or more digits OR any number greater than 150000 (starting with `[1-9][5-9]` OR `[2-9][0-9]` AND any other 4 digits.

Base regex:

`(\d{7,}|(?:[1-9][5-9]|[2-9][0-9])\d{4})`

Regex applyed to your case (matching entire line with a group for the number):

`^.*?(\d{7,}|(?:[1-9][5-9]|[2-9][0-9])\d{4}).*?$`

Try it here:

https://regex101.com/r/4TWiTf/3

Answer (score 0):

If your string format is the same every time, then you can try this code.

call method using  `findBiggerNumberFromGivenString(150000);`

```
/**
 * this method is used to find bigger number from given string 
 *
 * @param targetValue this will be your number
 */
private void findBiggerNumberFromGivenString(int targetValue) {
    String dataString = "time:9345 msec"; // your string
    String[] spitedString = dataString.split(":"); // this will split your sting from ":"
    int intData = Integer.parseInt(spitedString[1].split(" ")[0]); // this will split your string from blank space. then pick 1st data and convert into int

    if (intData > targetValue) {
        CustomLog.info("result", "biggerNumber");
    } else {
        CustomLog.info("result", "smallerNumber");
    }
}
```